# Questions on hexadecimal-notation for primitive initialization

Tags: java, double, hex

I would like to initialize a `double` directly by using the hexadecimal-notation. I know this works for `int` and `Long` as shown in the following example (resulting values always right):

```
    int i   = 0x10000000;           // 268435456
    Long li = 0x1000000000000000L;  // 1152921504606846976
```

On the other hand, if I try do the same with doubles, it works but only in range of 4 Bytes (view comments in the code example). For the second, not valid notation the Netbeans IDE keeps telling me that is is an integer value and, thus, too large:

```
    double d1 = 0x10000000;         // 2.68435456E8
    double d2 = 0x1000000000000000; // not valid
```

`float`-values work as well as they are in the range of 4 Bytes:

```
float f1 = 0x10000000;              // 2.68435456E8
```

---

1. **Is there a way to directly write/initialize a double with hexadecimal-notation?**
2. **Is the only reason for being able to write a `Long` with hex-notation that there is no "L" in this notation** (in contrast to "f" for float or the not valid "." for marking doubles)**?**
3. **Why is there a limitation to 4 Bytes? And why does it apply to `double` and not to `Long`?**

Thank you for your advise and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to initialize your double with an integer value in the long range, use:

```
double d2 = 0x1000000000000000L;
```

You can also supply integer hexadecimal values outside the long range using BigInteger:

```
double d3 = new BigInteger("123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0", 16).doubleValue();
```

If you need to supply hexadecimal fractions, as suggested in the previous answer, use a hexadecimal floating point literal:

```
double d = 0x1F.1p1;
```

Comment: Could you please add Evgeniy Dorofeev`s floating-point hexadecimal literals to your answer and I will close this question with your post as answer.

Comment: Done, but please also upvote Evgeniy Dorofeev`s answer.

Answer (score 2):

Java supports floating-point hexadecimal literals since 1.5

```
double d = 0x1f.1p1;
```

Comment: I didn't know of this kind of notation. It works, nontheless. I think the answer to my last question could be quite easy: The Compiler cannot but evaluate the `0x1000000000000000` as integer because there is nothing which tells it what else it should be before assigned to a `double`-variable.